# How to extract JSON/Table from a javascript variable in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, powerbi

I have been trying to **scrape** https://support.riverbed.com/content/support/eos_eoa.html which contains a paginated table generated in javascript.

I am currently using beautiful soup to capture the script element. However the variable EOL_ENTRIES hold the data I need but I am unable to parse it. Any tips on how to successfully **scrape** the data.

The ultimate aim is to actually put this data in PowerBI, However PBI is only able to **scrape** the first page.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = httplib2.Http()
url='https://support.riverbed.com/content/support/eos_eoa.html'
resp, data = http.request(url)
html = data.decode("UTF-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

#the 37th script which contains the data
script_with_data = soup.find_all('script')[37]
```

The Sample output looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var EOL_ENTRIES = [
            
            
            
            
                
                    
                    
                        
                    
                    
                
                {
                    productFamily: 'SteelCentral',
                    shortName: 'SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9',
                    link: 'https:\/\/support.riverbed.com\/content\/support\/eos_eoa\/steelcentral-cascade-opnet\/SteelCentral-AppInternals-Console-v9-and-AppInternals-Collector-v9-BrowserMetrix-OnPremise.html',
                    linkOverride: 'https:\/\/support.riverbed.com\/content\/support\/eos_eoa\/steelcentral-cascade-opnet\/SteelCentral-AppInternals-Console-v9-and-AppInternals-Collector-v9-BrowserMetrix-OnPremise.html',
                    sku: 'AIXCOL',
                    skuOverride: '',
                    description: 'SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9',
                    limitedAvailability: '',
                    limitedAvailabilityFormatted: '',
                    endOfAvailability: 'Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 PDT 2019',
                    endOfAvailabilityFormatted: 'Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 PDT 2019',
                    endOfSupportFeatures: 'Sat Aug 31 00:00:00 PDT 2019',
                    endOfSupportFeaturesFormatted: 'Sat Aug 31 00:00:00 PDT 2019',
                    endOfSupportMaintenance: 'Sat Aug 31 00:00:00 PDT 2019',
                    endOfSupportMaintenanceFormatted: 'Sat Aug 31 00:00:00 PDT 2019'}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is in JavaScript, so you need some preprocessing to be able to load it with `json` module:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://support.riverbed.com/content/support/eos_eoa.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html5lib')

# select <script> tag of interest
s = soup.find(lambda t: t.name == 'script' and 'var EOL_ENTRIES' in t.text)

# extract string from this script tag
t = re.search(r'var EOL_ENTRIES = (\[.*\]);', s.text, flags=re.S)[1]

# preprocess the string
t = t.replace("'", '"')
t = re.sub(r'^(\s*)(.*?):', r'\1"\2":', t, flags=re.M)

# decode string to Python data
data = json.loads(t)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
for product in data:
    print('{:<40} {:<40} {}'.format(product['sku'], product['productFamily'], product['shortName']))
```

Prints:

```
AIXCOL                                   SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
AIXCOL-AN                                SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
AIXCOL-LP                                SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
AIXCOL-LP-MODEL                          SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
AIXCOL-LS                                SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
AIXCOL-LS-MODEL                          SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
AIXCOL-SITE                              SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
AIXCOL-SUB-LIC                           SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9
PANCOL                                   SteelCentral                             SteelCentral AppInternals Collector v9


... and so on.
```

Comment: This worked like a charm @Andrej Thank you very much for your help! Dumped it to a json file and imported it to powerbi

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the data into Power BI, I would take a different approach: extract the data and load it into a dataframe, which can then be exported to Excel/CSV which PBI can read.

So I would try this:

```
import pandas as pd    
prods = str(script_with_data).split('var EOL_ENTRIES = [')[1].split('}')[0].replace('\t','').replace('\n','').split(',')
    rows = []
    for prod in prods:
        row = []
        row.extend([prod.split(': ')[0],prod.split(': ')[1].replace("'","")])
        rows.append(row)
    
    pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

and from here use standard panda methods to export the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer jack, however this will yield a two column output which cannot be transformed (using the pivot function) to get the data laid out as its shown in the website

Comment: @Tango_charlie Probably; I just went with the sample you posted in the question.