# How can I get the value of a JS variable when parsing in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, beautifulsoup, request

When collecting data from one site, I received the following html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var g_rgAppContextData = {"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","icon":"https:\/\/cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg","link":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/730"}};
</script>
```

How i can get that JSON data from variable?

I tried a lot of solutions found on the internet and nothing worked

Comment: With your tags not providing much info, I'd say you need to do an ajax post to whatever server you are using to run the html with that value.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals."_ Your code contains a JavaScript object literal and no JSON. You can either try to extract the code and process it (can be complex and not really stable) or you can evaluate the JavaScript and read the variable, e.g. with Selenium.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract JSON/Table from a javascript variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556397/how-to-extract-json-table-from-a-javascript-variable-in-python)

Comment: Be honest - no, i just lerning all of this

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution shamelessly ripped from another answer on this site ([How to extract JSON/Table from a javascript variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556397/how-to-extract-json-table-from-a-javascript-variable-in-python)):

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_txt = '''
<script type="text/javascript">
        var g_rgAppContextData = {"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","icon":"https:\/\/cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg","l>
</script>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_txt, "html.parser")

var_to_extract = "g_rgAppContextData"

s = soup.find(lambda t: t.name == 'script' and f'var {var_to_extract}' in t.text)

t = re.search('var ' + var_to_extract + ' = (\{.*\});', s.text, flags=re.S)[1]

t = t.replace("'", '"')

data = json.loads(t)

print(data)
print(type(data))
print(print(data["730"]["name"]))
```

Output:

```
{'730': {'appid': 730, 'name': 'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive', 'icon': 'https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg', 'link': 'https://steamcommunity.com/app/730'}}
<class 'dict'>
Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
```

Comment: if you found another solution on StackOverflow, then you should flag the question as a duplicate

Comment: 95% of StackOverflow is people tagging duplicate posts. There are several key differences between my answer and the one I linked.

Comment: Yes, because more often than not, questions are duplicate. What is the relevant difference here?

Comment: I suppose you're capable of looking at the other post to determine that. Given you expect everyone asking a question to perform an exhaustive search of SO before asking a question that has never been thought of before.

Comment: No, I expect people to at least do a minimal google search and I expect those who find suitable duplicates to flag them as such. I don't understand this hostility towards flagging duplicates. I asked you because to me, the question looks essentially the same, and the answer looks essentially the same, use `soup.find` to find a script tag with particular text that contains the variable name, then process that text to turn into a valid JSON, then use `json` to deserialize it.

Comment: I have had several of my questions incorrectly duplicated by over ambitious members of the community such as yourself. The OP clearly stated that they have searched the web and hadn't found a solution. The answer I linked was the top Google result, but required a minor amount of adjustments before it could address their use case. I assume the OP viewed the issue, but couldn't get it to work correctly. It baffles me why you'd want to duplicate a question instead of providing assistance to someone who is asking for it.

Comment: @Matt Stack Overflow has the goal to collect questions and answers to help future users with similar problems, not to help one single individual. It's not helpful to write duplicate answers. It's better to collect all answer under one question and link to this question. If your answer is missing under that other question, add it there and link it here.

Comment: @jabaa I refuse to acknowledge your position. This conversation has taken up more space than both question and answer combined. If I am looking and someone has a question, I will answer it to the best of my ability. If you're worried about accumulating cruft on this site I would suggest you stop participating in arguments in the comments of question that "should be duplicated".